# Copying an int to a struct object

Tags: c#, structure, managed-c++

I have a structure definition in C++ as below

```
typedef struct                                                                                      
{
    unsigned __int32   SetCommonPOP:1;
    unsigned __int32   SetCommonSVP:1;
    unsigned __int32   SetCommonUHDP:1;
    unsigned __int32   SetCommonMHDP:1;

    unsigned __int32   MinPwdLength:8;
    unsigned __int32   MaxPwdLength:8;
    unsigned __int32   StoredHdpBackups:8;
} HPM_PWD_CONSTRAINTS;
```

I translated that to c# as below

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=28, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct HPM_PWD_CONSTRAINTS                                                                                   
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public uint   SetCommonPOP;
    [FieldOffset(1)] public uint   SetCommonSVP;
    [FieldOffset(2)] public uint   SetCommonUHDP;
    [FieldOffset(3)] public uint   SetCommonMHDP;

    [FieldOffset(4)] public uint   MinPwdLength;
    [FieldOffset(12)] public uint   MaxPwdLength;
    [FieldOffset(20)] public uint   StoredHdpBackups;

};
```

The code in c++ which I am converting to c# defines an object PWD of this structure and passes the value of an int x to this object.

```
*((uint*)&PWD) = x;
```

How does this work? What would be the value of the structure object after this? How do I convert this to C#?

Comment: The first four `uint`s in the struct should probably be `bytes`.

Comment: The first rule of SO is..... :P

Answer (score 1):

The C++ structure is defining bits of a single 32-bit unsigned integer. The `SetCommonPOP` field is actually the least significant bit of the four byte structure.

You cannot convert this directly to C#, even with `FieldOffset`. Rather, treat the value as a `uint` and perform bit manipulation to read the separate fields.

Here's a link that should better explain bit fields in C++, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This code unsafely converts the struct pointer into a pointer to a `uint`, then writes the specified `uint` into that bit of memory.

This overwrites the first four bytes of overlapped fields to hold the value of the `uint`.

The equivalent C# code is exactly the same, within an `unsafe` method.
You could also simply set the `SetCommonPOP` field of the struct; since it's a `uint` the occupied the beginning of the struct, that would have the same effect.

Comment: @S Laks I edited the question. It was defined as uint in c++ which is why I left it as it is rather than using a byte for the first 4 members

Comment: When using FieldOFfset, are the members stored in memory from LSB to MSB? Is that why the first four members only get assigned?
Also, in that case what would be the values of the remaining 3 members? 0?